# While installing maven project, I am getting DependencyConvergence error

Tags: java, maven

```
[WARNING] Rule 3: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
    Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
    Dependency convergence error for xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04 paths to 
    dependency are:
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.:string-converter:5.0
        +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
          +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
            +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:1.7
              +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
        +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
          +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
            +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.7
              +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
        +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
          +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
            +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:1.7
              +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
     and
     +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
       +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
         +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
           +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.7
             +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
     and
     +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
       +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
         +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
           +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.7
             +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
     and
     +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
       +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
         +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
           +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:1.7
             +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
     and
     +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
       +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
         +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
           +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.7
             +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
     and
     +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
       +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
         +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
           +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:1.7
             +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
        +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.7
          +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
        +-com.cer.clinrpt.core:cr-core:6.0
         +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
        +-com.clip.editor:cr-core:6.0
          +-org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:1.7
            +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.print.processor:string-converter:5.0
        +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
    and
    +-com.print.attend: printview: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
        +-com.print.common.procedural:common-procedural-jsap:1.0
          +-org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.4.0.GA
            +-dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
              +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
```

While installing maven project on intellij, I am getting this error. How to 
    resolve this?

Comment: You have one dependency `+-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2` in your tree which is not the same as `xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04` and that's the reason for that failure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DependencyConvergence rule checks whether the same dependency is found in different versions in the dependency tree.

If it finds different versions and no dependencyManagement entry is given, it will fail the build.

You can either

- define a dependencyManagement entry that sets a version for `xml-apis`.
- figure out why different versions came into the dependency tree and change the dependencies so that this does not happen.
- deactivate the dependencyConvergence rule.

Comment: How to figure out the reason for different versions?

Comment: All but one of your dependencies have `xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04`, but one has a different version. So maybe this one different version is an "error".

Comment: Yes. So I was thinking to exclude this artifact (xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2). But from where to exclude? I mean from which dependency, should I exclude?

Comment: I guess from `com.print.common.procedural:common-procedural-jsap:1.0`.

Comment: I have excluded xml-apis from com.print.common.procedural:common-procedural-jsap:1.0. This error is comming. I dont have any idea about this error. Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.ReactorModuleConvergence failed with message:
Module parents have been found which could not be found in the reactor.

Comment: This is a different error, I would suggest your write a new question for that.